# Rotation is to translation as angle is to _?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I would like to know the (a) word that describes all units in relation to translation. Similar to how degrees and radians are both angles, inches and feet must have a more abstract term that encompass them both. Such a term would fit the analogy of the title of this post.

Comment: The obvious one is "distance"

Comment: How common is it to delete your new English Language & Usage Stack Exchange account?

Comment: It would probably be distance or measurement

Comment: "measurements" or "dimensions" or "length"

Comment: @KNOBPersonal Are you aking how to delete the account?

Comment: @Ian54 No I am asking if I should. I don't need it anymore and I feel like an idiot for not realizing that it was "distance."

Comment: @KNOB Personal - No need to delete your account. You can if you wish delete this *question*. Or you can just let it fade into the background and never be seen again.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica I'm just going to forget I ever uploaded it. Maybe I'll have a good laugh over it when I find it again next year.

Comment: Displacement; a rotational is essentially unidirectional (+ or -) whereas a translation may be 3-dimensional.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth...and then there is higher-dimensional rotation and translation.

Comment: Edwin's got it. _Displacement_ refers to translation in one dimension only.

Comment: @JohnLawler - What muddies the water here is the prevalence of the term *angular displacement*.  A rotation results in an angular displacement.  A rotation about a single axis is measured by an angle. A translation along a single axis is measured by a distance.  A multi-dimensional translation is measured by a vector. A rotation about an arbitrary axis is defined by, for example, a quaternion.

Comment: So call it a displacement vector. You don't need a one-word phrase for everything. Most predicates in natural language have more than one argument, just like functions.